# How to get currently selected columns in Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Having a object of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` type, how can I access the array of currently selected columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the public `$columns` property from the base query builder:

```php
$columns = $query->getQuery()->columns;
```